# Duplicate content in multi-volume monograph

Tags: publications, editors, books, monograph

A scientist writes a multi-volume monograph reflecting his latest research results.

In the first volume a certain topic is presented but incompletely because at the time of writing the research on this topic was partial.

In the second volume, more research on the topic is presented and the researcher wants to present the topic systematically. Because of this the researcher wants to repeat information that is already contained in the first volume (otherwise it cannot be presented systematically enough). This amounts to about 8 % of the pages of the first volume.

Question: What response does the researcher have to expect from book editors for duplicating information on the topic **which was already published in the first volume**?

Comment: _duplicate in second volume the former research done in the first volume_, How much will be duplicated in the second volume?

Comment: I think about 15%

Comment: I calculated: 8% of the pages of the first volume.

Answer (score 5):

> What will be the response of the book editors for duplicating in the second volume information on topic X which was already published in the first volume?

This is unlikely to be viewed positively.  One obvious question is why not prepare a second edition of the first volume, rather than duplicating this information in the second volume?  Duplication seems like a strange solution to this problem.  However, there's a deeper issue:

In mathematics, books are not the primary mechanism for disseminating research results.  Instead, a subject is ready for treatment in the form of a book when it is relatively well explored and understood, so that you can write a coherent and definitive account.  If you are afraid that the subject will progress so quickly that volume one would be an inadequate foundation for volume two, then this is not the right time to publish the book.  I do not believe any reputable, mainstream publisher would publish a book under these circumstances.

Comment: But I have already written a book and put it at my Web site. I consider not to publish it officially at all, but instead put its LaTeX source online under a copyleft license. If the World will ignore my research because not disseminated in "academic" way, it's World's problem not mine.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you are asking.  Is your question whether self-publishing the first volume would make traditional publishers unwilling to publish a second volume that overlaps with it?  (Maybe, but they might view the first volume as unpublished, in which case it might not bother them.)