# A conjecture proved in drafts

Tags: publications, research-process, mathematics, books

I am preparing my math research monograph for publication.

In the current draft there is certain conjecture.

This conjecture was proved in my drafts (available on the Web) of the second volume for this monograph.

Should I:

1. just remove the conjecture from the book because it is proved?
2. leave the statement in the book titled as a conjecture because it's proof is not yet officially published (and also may be not enough checked for errors)?
3. write in the book that I am going to publish the proof (either in a separate article or the second volume of the book)?

Comment: I think this has already been answered in [response to another of your questions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/51203/11365): "a subject is ready for treatment in the form of a book when it is relatively well explored and understood, so that you can write a coherent and definitive account. " You are facing this problem because you are ignoring the advice you've previously been given and trying to write a monograph on a subject that isn't fully understood yet.

Comment: @ff524 1. "response to another of your questions" is literally a response to a different question, this question is different, that response is not to this question. 2. Of all forms of publication I have chosen to put my book online under a copyleft license and just put it online. But as an additional "venue" I have also submitted my book to a monographs competition. Note that I distribute the volume 1 (which I am currently checking for errors) together with drafts related to the second volume.

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is a different question. I think that part of the answer answers this question as well, even though it was written for a different question.

Comment: Are you submitting this work to peer-reviewed journals? If not, why not?

Comment: @user37208 My current decision is not to submit it to peer-reviewed journals, because: it is already accessible through Internet, I have no scientific degree and so no scientific career (in the form of money) which peer reviewed publications would foster, splitting a book into articles diminishes rather than increases the scientific value of the text, making articles out of the book is some additional work. However I am open to the proposition "split your book into parts and publish the parts", if you explain **why** to do this.

Comment: @porton Well, for starters, what do you suppose the odds are that the community will view "Harry Potter and the proof of the Riemann Hypothesis" seriously when you have *nothing* to lend weight and credence to your methods, insights, or erudition?  Articles undergo peer review.  Books, not so much.  And for pre-starters, the previously mentioned answers to your prior question are precisely the explanation you are asking for.

Comment: @porton Simple: other researchers will be orders of magnitude more likely to take your work seriously if it makes it through peer-review. I assume your goal is to communicate your research to others, or you wouldn't be asking this question. Even if your work is good, you have to give people a reason to pay attention to it. There is quite a lot of amateur math research of dubious quality floating around the internet, so people are understandably skeptical.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy My response to this is that my LaTeX files are available for forking and independent editing by anybody. This should spot errors in my book more accurately than peer review. Splitting my books into parts, just to ensure that somebody put his checkmark onto it, looks like an unnecessary work for me. My book (I speak about volume 1) is very basic in prerequisites, so it is expected that any undergraduate mathematician. The community is expected to the work

Comment: @porton Why would anyone want to do that, though?  I sure don't want to.  I'm not going to randomly stumble onto your work, and I'm not going to randomly start doing your work for you for nothing.  If you submit it to a journal and I was selected as a referee then if the paper passes first muster I might put some effort into it.  But we have lives, you know?  And what's more likely: a random ignorant schmuck who thinks he's Einstein edits your work, or Terrence Tao edits your work?  There is a HUGE difference between "professional and expert" and "random internet guy".

Comment: There are too many things to be done to invest time+energy in less-obviously-productive courses. Without previously established "credibility" (whatever we make of this precisely...) there is scant motivation for relatively-expert people to spend time on a large document. In particular, experts have no _obligation_ to look at every thing on the internet and correct or critique it. Many things simply languish. Thus, if you want useful feedback, you'll want to establish some credibility, which probably means playing the traditional game to some extent... not that I'm a fan of tradition.

Comment: _My current decision is not to submit it to peer-reviewed journals, because: it is already accessible through Internet_ — The only way to find out whther your results are interesting and believable to anyone but yourself is to _ask them_. And the standard mechanism for asking is to submit the work for peer review. By refusing to _actively_ seek feedback from the research community, you are labeling yourself a crank.

Comment: @JeffE Well, I have already published one article. The main article (based on the first one) on which the monograph is based was accepted for publication, but publication didn't happen due a LaTeX error. I have resubmitted my article later with a couple of additional theorems. They said that it needs peer review again because I added new theorems. Today I've inquired them about the status of my article. I think publication of these two articles may be enough, just to show that the main idea of the book is credible. The rest of the book is just further development of ideas from that article

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important principles of academic writing is that you shouldn't write anything misleading.  If you present the result as a conjecture with no indication that you have already proved it, then you are giving readers a misleading impression (namely that you don't know how to prove it), so you shouldn't do that.

> Should I just remove the conjecture from the book because it is proved?

That's an acceptable option.

> Should I leave the statement in the book titled as a conjecture because it's proof is not yet officially published (and also may be not enough checked for errors)?

Don't just leave it there without comment.  If you are worried that the proof might be wrong, you can address this by stating things a little more tentatively.  As for whether it is officially published, most of your work seems not to be officially published, so why is that an issue for this conjecture?

> Should I write in the book that I am going to publish the proof (either in a separate article or the second volume of the book)?

Sure, why not?  It's probably preferable to deleting the conjecture: if it was worth mentioning as a conjecture, then presumably it's still worth mentioning as a theorem.